# How to fix undefined error in php

Tags: php

I have a problem to fix this type error, I am also declare the variable the its given a problem.

This is my complete file:

```
$success='';
$error1='';
$valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');

$max_file_size = 2000* 1024; #200kb

$nw = $nh = 50;
# image with # height

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))  
{
    $title=$_REQUEST['title'];
    $date=date('d-M-Y');
    /****prod image*******************************/
    $fn1=$_FILES['image']['name'];

    $fs1=$_FILES['image']['size'];

    $ftemp1=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $img_type1=$_FILES['image']['type'];

    if(! $_FILES['image']['error'] && $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_file_size) {
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts))
        {
            // Check if file already exists
            $path = 'image/thumb/'.$fn1;
            $size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

            $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
            $y = (int) $_POST['y'];
            $w = (int) $_POST['w'] ? $_POST['w'] : $size[0];
            $h = (int) $_POST['h'] ? $_POST['h'] : $size[1];

            $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $vImg = imagecreatefromstring($data);
            $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
            imagecopyresampled($dstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, $x, $y, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
            imagejpeg($dstImg, $path);
            imagedestroy($dstImg);

            if(move_uploaded_file ($ftemp1,"image/$fn1")){
                $result="INSERT INTO add_banner VALUES ('','$title','$fn1','$date')";
                if(mysql_query($result)){

                    //echo "<script>alert('Banner Added Successfully !');</script>";
                    $success='<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully add the banner.</div>';

                    // echo "<script>document.location.href='front_banner.php'</script>";
                } else {
                    $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.</div>';
                    //echo "<script>document.location.href='front_banner.php'</script>";
                }
            } else {
                $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.</div>';
                //echo "<script>document.location.href='front_banner.php'</script>";
            }
        } else {
            $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</div>';         
        }
    } else {
        $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Sorry, Please fill the Field</div>';
    }
}
```

This is my output:

> **Notice**: Undefined index: x in
>   **E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php on
>   line **28**
>  
>  **Notice**: Undefined index: y in
>   **E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php on
>   line **29**
>  
>  **Notice**: Undefined index: w in
>   **E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php on
>   line 30**
>  
>  Notice**: Undefined index: h in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php on
>   line 31**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: God that opening sentence...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($success)) { echo $success ; } .''.if(isset($error1)) { echo $error1 ;}.''.if(isset($error)) { echo $error;}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the variables in your php-file where you set it.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$success = "";
$error1 = "";
$error = "";
```

Then you can be sure that your vars are not undefined and you can use them without this "undefined error".

After these lines, you can do whatever you wanna do.

**EDIT**

Looks like your `$_POST['x']`, `$_POST['y']`, `$_POST['w']`, `$_POST['h']` is not set. Try to `var_dump($_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'])` to see if it's filled.

You could check if this is set with:

```
if ($_POST['x'] != "" && $_POST['y'] != "" && $_POST['w'] != "" && $_POST['h'] != "") {
```

or

```
if (!empty($_POST['x']) && !empty($_POST['y']) && !empty($_POST['w']) && !empty($_POST['h'])) {
```

or

```
if (isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['y']) && isset($_POST['w']) && isset($_POST['h'])) {

    $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
    $y = (int) $_POST['y'];
    $w = (int) $_POST['w'] ? $_POST['w'] : $size[0];
    $h = (int) $_POST['h'] ? $_POST['h'] : $size[1];

    // do your thing ...
} else {
    $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Blablabla </div>';         
}
```

**EDIT 2**

At the point where you ask if `if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts))`, add the code from my first EDIT below. This could look like this:

```
if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
    if ($_POST['x'] != "" && $_POST['y'] != "" && $_POST['w'] != "" && $_POST['h'] != "") {

        // ...
        // here is your code where you set $x, $y, $w, $h and the other things
        // ...

    } else {
        $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Blablabla </div>';         
    }
} else {
    $error1='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</div>';         
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: x in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: y in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: w in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: h in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\front_banner.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />

Comment: i am not get the solution can you provide a full solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your problem but this code looks better to show error's message.

```
<?php
if(isset($success) && !empty($success))
{
    echo $success." ";
}
if(isset($error1) && !empty($success))
{
    echo $success." ";
}
if(isset($success) && !empty($success))
{
    echo $success;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```
<?php
$success = "";
$error1 = "";
$error = "";

if (isset($success)) echo $success;
if (isset($error1)) echo $error1;
if (isset($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST['x']` value and other for indexes `y`, `w` and `h` are not defined. So you have to check it before use it.

For example, try

```
$x = (isset($_POST['x'])? (int) $_POST['x'] : 0;
```

Do the same for `$_POST['y']`, and for `h` and `w` you'd better write something as following (I used if condition for better readability):

```
if (isset($_POST['h']) && ((int) $_POST['h'] > 0)) {
    $h = (int) $_POST['h'] ;
} else {
    $h = $size['h'] ;
}
```

Of course, check the submition of your POST too, as it seems it does not defined these values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$x = (int) ( isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : 0 );
$y = (int) ( isset($_POST['y']) ? $_POST['y'] : 0 );
$w = (int) ( isset($_POST['w']) ? $_POST['w'] : $size[0] );
$h = (int) ( isset($_POST['h']) ? $_POST['h'] : $size[1] );
```

Comment: I have got this error                                                                              <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  getimagesize(): Read error! in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\article_add.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\article_add.php</b> on line <b>58</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\novus_admin_panel\web\article_add.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />

Comment: The `Read error!` may happen if the file did not upload correctly, or if you don't specify the proper full path to the file or if the file has 0 bytes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php